# Creating iPhone app using phonegap on Windows7

Tags: ios, cordova

```
C:\soft\my-app>phonegap create something
[phonegap] create called with the options C:\soft\my-app\something com.phonegap.helloworld HelloWorld
[phonegap] Customizing default config.xml file
[phonegap] created project at C:\soft\my-app\something


cd something

C:\soft\my-app\something>phonegap build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment... 
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the iOS platform...
{ [CordovaError: Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32.]
  name: 'CordovaError',
  message: 'Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32.' }
   [error] Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32.
[phonegap] using the remote environment
{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\soft\my-app\something\www\config.xml']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\soft\\my-app\\something\\www\\config.xml' }
   [error] ENOENT, open 'C:\soft\my-app\something\www\config.xml'
```

When I look at windows information (Right click on my computer) it shows windows OS as 64 bit.

What could be causing this issue ?  I am trying to develop iphone app on windows 7. I installed node.js and phonegap using following command:  npm install -g phonegap

Do I need to install cordova ?

Answer (score 2):

What Scott Hunter said isn't entirely true, you can build IOS using windows.
It will use [phonegap build](http://build.phonegap.com) to compile the code as is shown by this line "[phonegap] using the remote environment"

I am having the same issue as OP though, I'm thinking its a bug. As I haven't had issues in the past and just recently upgraded and tried to create a new project.

Edit: Downgrading to an older version should work, its looking like:
npm -g install phonegap@3.5.0-0.21.18

Answer (score 0):

You can't build an iOS app on anything other than Mac OSX.

Comment: Then why they give .bat files.

Comment: You'd have to ask them