# Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32

Tags: ios, cordova

When i try to add IOS platform on my cordova project, i've got this error :

**Applications for platform ios can not be built on this OS - win32**

I'm on a 64bits windows 8.1 computer. I know i can't buid ios project from Windows but i think i can add ios platform such as android to my project.

Is anyone already have this error message ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating iPhone app using phonegap on Windows7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416270/creating-iphone-app-using-phonegap-on-windows7)

Answer (score 7):

You are missing **prerequisites**:

To add a project for a platform, you need to run the CL interface from the same machine that supports the platform's SDK. The CLI supports the following combinations:

- iOS (Mac)
- Android (Mac, Linux)
- Blackberry (Mac, Windows)
- Windows Phone 7 (Windows)
- Windows Phone 8 (Windows)

read this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html

Comment: Link to latest documentation: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#install-pre-requisites-for-building